# pifacecad file or directory not found

Tags: piface

The pi itself works. Pifacecad was installed using the Farnell setup pages and seemed to be accepted. However when testing the sysinfo.py file it reported that the file or directory could not be located. The LCD showed either nothing or black blocks instead of characters. Should I be loading something else that contains this file?
Thanks in anticipation, Alan

Comment: You need to add URL's to stuff you refers to. And please add the complete error, not just a vauge reference.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi :-) Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.